# Mysql returns NULL instead of a value

Tags: mysql, orange-pi

I had a local server (apache, php, mysql) running on my computer and everything was just fine. But I decided to migrate it on an orangePi. Now I have the problem, that when I write something in my database, then everything works, but when I try to read it using this code:

```
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $table ) as $row)
        $val[$val_len++] = $row;
```

I get the correct number of rows, but all the values are NULL. 
Help me please, I have no idea what's going on

Comment: Are you able to use a mysql workbench to check the values in the table?

Comment: I just use the terminal, but yes I can check the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just debug if the php query("SELECT * FROM " . $table ) as $row can return the value,
if not check the datasource whether it is the expected db host and database or not